# Adding query clause to cakephp find operation

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a standard find query on my user model that looks as followed:

```
$user = $this->User->find( 'all', array( 'conditions' => array( 'User.id' => $user_id ) ) );
```

I also have some extensions I would like to make to the where clause of this function call like so:

```
$query_extension = 'AND users.id IN ( complex join between a few tables )';
```

I want to add this complex WHERE clause on to the end of that user find condition, but I'm not sure how to do this. I'm looking into the ConnectionManager class, but I'm still not sure how to append this extra clause:

http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-ConnectionManager.html#_getDataSource

Comment: Kind of hard to say without knowing the exact query you're trying to write, but you can make a query with a manual join, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables .

Comment: @kai what is in the `IN` clause is not important. I'm just trying to find a way to append the `IN` clause regardless of what's in it.

Comment: Read the [section in the cookbook regarding subqueries](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries). If it doesn't meet your need, let us know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how this operation can be preformed. Notice that the clause being added to the main query includes an `AND` This means that it is actually part of the where clause and can be added as a string to a find as followed.

```
// Note here that including the $complex_subselect_string as an un-keyed term in the conditions automatically ANDs this extra query clause
$complete_user_list = $this->find( 'all', array( 'conditions' => array( $complex_subselect_string ), 'limit' => $limit, 'contain' => array() ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check sample code I used, you can also set dynamic content like `joins` Will have array What you built Or 
will have blank array.

```
$courseNames = $this->UsersCourse->Course->find('list',
            array('fields'=> array('Course.course_name'),
                  'order'=> array('Course.course_name'),                   
                  'conditions'=>array('Course.is_active'=>1 ,
                                      'CourseCategory.is_active'=>1
                                      ),
                    "joins" => array(
                                array(
                                    "table" => "course_categories",
                                    "alias" => "CourseCategory",
                                    "type" => "INNER",
                                    "conditions" => array(
                                        "CourseCategory.id = Course.course_category_id"
                                    )
                                )
                            )                                                                                                                              
                  )
```

);